# ¿Cómo unir audio con vídeo FFmpeg?

Tags: video

Hola amigos quiero unir un vídeo con audio con FFmpeg pero me gustaría que el audio comience 20 seg después que el vídeo.
Tengo este comando

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i snido.mp3 -map 0:v:0 -map 2:a:0 -y out.mp4
```

pero inicia todo al mismo tiempo.

Alguna ayuda o comentario soy nuevo con FFmpeg Gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Este comando te debe servir sin problemas:

> -ss seguido del numero de segundos a partir del cual empezar

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i snido.mp3 -ss 20 -map 0:v:0 -map 2:a:0 -y out.mp4
```

si requieres especificar cuantos segundos de duración del sonido le agregas **-t**, aquí te pongo un ejemplo que empieza a partir del segundo 20 y termina 40 segundos después de empezar en total de 20 hasta 60

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i snido.mp3 -ss 20 -t 40 -map 0:v:0 -map 2:a:0 -y out.mp4
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el apoyo, intentandolo reproduce el sonido al comienzo del video pero a partir del segundo 20 de la canción

Answer (score 0):

Puede usar el filtro [adelay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#adelay). Este filtro permite retrasar uno a más canales de audio. Este filtro se puede usar en la opción `-af` para aplicarlo sobre el stream de audio. Asumiendo que es un audio estéreo (2 canales), se podría usar de la siguiente forma:

```bash
-af 'adelay=20000|20000'
```

El tiempo de retraso en milisegundos se especifica para cada canal usando `|` como separador. En este caso se está retrasando en 20000 ms (20 s) para ambos canales.

Aplicado al comando de la pregunta quedaría así:

```bash
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i snido.mp3 -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -af 'adelay=20000|20000' -y out.mp4
```

Creo que en la pregunta hay un error al usar `-map 2:a:0` porque solo hay dos entradas, la `0` y la `1`.